# Upload list to server

Tags: java, android

I want to save a new `ParseObject` ([used to store data on Parse](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-classes_anchor)) to the server. Here is my code:

```
private List<String> groupFreindsName = new ArrayList<String>();
if (groupFreindsName.size() > 0) {
    Log.d("group", "query success");
    final ParseObject saleObj = new ParseObject("all");
    saleObj.put("type", "g");
    saleObj.addAll("groupFreindsName", groupFreindsName);
    saleObj.put("ppp", "ppp");
    saleObj.saveInBackground();
}
```

However it doesn't save it to the server; when I debugged it I see that it enter to this method and into the `saveInBackground()` method. I can't see the object on the server, however.

If I remove the line:

```
    saleObj.addAll("groupFreindsName", groupFreindsName);
```

it successfully uploads the object.

Also, in both times the `groupFreindsName` list is not empty and contains strings
and in both times I don't get an exception.

here is the logcat:

```
04-03 20:32:27.723: D/dalvikvm(1249): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1624K, 12% free 28407K/32036K, paused 118ms, total 131ms
04-03 20:32:29.153: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 267 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:30.693: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:32.893: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1249): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
04-03 20:32:32.893: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1249):   in android.widget.EditText{4121a9a0 VFED..CL .F....I. 0,493-425,538 #7f0800a5 app:id/descriptionTextGroup}
04-03 20:32:32.893: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1249):   0: sent at 973006000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_G, scanCode=34, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=973006, downTime=972697, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
04-03 20:32:32.893: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1249):   -- recent events --
04-03 20:32:32.893: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1249):   1: sent at 972697535000, MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=139.0, y[0]=26.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=972697, downTime=972661, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-03 20:32:32.893: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1249):   2: sent at 972661805000, MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=139.0, y[0]=26.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=972661, downTime=972661, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-03 20:32:35.394: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:35.633: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:36.663: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:36.823: D/dalvikvm(1249): GC_CONCURRENT freed 856K, 8% free 29608K/32036K, paused 105ms+95ms, total 366ms
04-03 20:32:39.274: D/dalvikvm(1249): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1433K, 6% free 30153K/32036K, paused 121ms+137ms, total 377ms
04-03 20:32:39.683: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:40.384: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:40.844: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 113 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:41.154: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:43.193: D/group(1249): query success
04-03 20:32:46.683: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 20:32:48.593: D/dalvikvm(1249): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1725K, 6% free 30261K/32144K, paused 111ms, total 130ms
04-03 20:32:48.593: I/dalvikvm-heap(1249): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.103MB for 456992-byte allocation
04-03 20:32:48.723: D/dalvikvm(1249): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1086K, 10% free 29621K/32592K, paused 98ms, total 98ms
04-03 20:32:50.233: D/onScroll(1249): enter onScroll3
```

here is an updated logcat:

```
04-04 07:11:00.231: W/System.err(1158): com.parse.ParseException: can't add objects for a field that isn't an array
04-04 07:11:00.281: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.ParseCommand$3.then(ParseCommand.java:340)
04-04 07:11:00.297: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:442)
04-04 07:11:00.297: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:67)
04-04 07:11:00.301: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:439)
04-04 07:11:00.301: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:316)
04-04 07:11:00.301: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:327)
04-04 07:11:00.301: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:377)
04-04 07:11:00.301: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:1)
04-04 07:11:00.301: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:474)
04-04 07:11:00.301: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:67)
04-04 07:11:00.311: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:471)
04-04 07:11:00.321: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.access$9(Task.java:467)
04-04 07:11:00.321: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
04-04 07:11:00.321: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:1)
04-04 07:11:00.336: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:502)
04-04 07:11:00.341: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.access$5(Task.java:498)
04-04 07:11:00.341: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:557)
04-04 07:11:00.341: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:591)
04-04 07:11:00.341: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
04-04 07:11:00.341: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:1)
04-04 07:11:00.341: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:442)
04-04 07:11:00.341: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:67)
04-04 07:11:00.341: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:439)
04-04 07:11:00.351: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.access$8(Task.java:435)
04-04 07:11:00.351: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:309)
04-04 07:11:00.351: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:1)
04-04 07:11:00.361: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:502)
04-04 07:11:00.361: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.access$5(Task.java:498)
04-04 07:11:00.361: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:557)
04-04 07:11:00.361: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:591)
04-04 07:11:00.361: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
04-04 07:11:00.361: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:1)
04-04 07:11:00.361: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:442)
04-04 07:11:00.371: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:67)
04-04 07:11:00.371: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:439)
04-04 07:11:00.371: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:316)
04-04 07:11:00.371: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:327)
04-04 07:11:00.371: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:478)
04-04 07:11:00.371: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:67)
04-04 07:11:00.371: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:471)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.access$9(Task.java:467)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:1)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:502)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task.access$5(Task.java:498)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:557)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:591)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at com.parse.Task$3.run(Task.java:225)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
04-04 07:11:00.381: W/System.err(1158):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
04-04 07:11:00.391: W/System.err(1158):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-04 07:11:00.391: W/System.err(1158):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-04 07:11:00.391: W/System.err(1158):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: There's little to be said here without knowing what the specification of the API is, and what it's responding with. I'm unfamiliar with Parse.com, if your problem is specific to that API.

Comment: please look at my post. may be it can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the possibility to use `addUnique` (adds an object to the array associated with a given key, only if it is not already present in the array.)

e.g.:

replace

```
 saleObj.addAll("groupFreindsName", groupFreindsName);
```

with

```
for(String value: groupFreindsName){
saleObj.addUnique("groupFreindsName", value);
}
```

or with

```
saleObj.add("groupFreindsName", groupFreindsName);
```

Comment: hi, thanks alot, i tried both answers however it didnt work for me

Comment: @AdirRahamim can you please post a full logcat output?

Comment: Again, if i remove the add live to saleObj it uploads it correctly

Comment: @AdirRahamim what are inside your arrayList?

Comment: @AdirRahamim just to try do this saleObj.add("groupFreindsName",Arrays.asList("test1", "test2")); and let me know

Comment: hi, i tried what you suggested: saleObj.add("groupFreindsName",Arrays.asList("test1", "test2")); and it still doesnt upload it to server, i think that this isnt the correct method to upload list with...so what is the correct method to upload a list with? thanks alot

Comment: @AdirRahamim. look at this (https://parse.com/docs/android_guide). I think your server has problem dealing with list

Comment: hi, i printed the stacktrace and i write it to the logcat, i updated the logcat in the main thread, hope that you could help me, thanks alot

Comment: @AdirRahamim it can ridiculous: put "s" at the end of your key. e.g: saleObj.add("groupFreindsNames",Arrays.asList("test1", "test2"));

Comment: @AdirRahamim if it still doesn't work then replace "add" with "put" and try again

Comment: @AdirRahamim which proposition helps at the end?